# Removing newlines in php

Tags: php

Following is the syntax for `preg_replace()` function in php:

```
$new_string = preg_replace($pattern_to_match, $replacement_string, $original_string);
```

if a text file has both Windows (rn) and Linux(n) End of line (EOL) characters i.e line feeds.

then which of the following is the correct order of applying `preg_replace()` to get rid of all end of line characters?

1. remove cr first

   ```
   $string = preg_replace('|rn|','',$string);
   $string = preg_replace('|n|','',$string);
   ```
2. remove plain nl first

   ```
   $string = preg_replace('|n|','',$string);
   $string = preg_replace('|rn|','',$string);
   ```

Comment: why do you think the order matters?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use: (Windows, Unix and Mac EOL characters)

```
$string = preg_replace('/\r|\n/m','',$string);
```

Notice `m` multiline modifier.

Comment: You don't need to replace \r\n if you're already replacing \r and \n

Answer (score 0):

Using the power of regular expressions, you could specify something like

```
'|[\r][\n]|'
```

which specifically mean, 0 or 1 '\r', then 0 or 1 '\n' which would match the end of a row under both linux and windows.

EDIT:
Using the build-in function [trim](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) would achieve the same result in an even better manner, but only if the newline characters are located at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: Plus that there's actually no need for regexes. str_replace will do the trick

Comment: As will 'trim', come to think of it.

Comment: According to php documentation (link in answer) it removes '\r', '\n', '\t', '\0', ' '  and '\x0B' (vertical tab).
However, keep in mind - it only does so from the start and end of string. These characters in the middle of a string will not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

> which of the following is the correct order of applying preg_replace to get rid of all end of line characters?

```
$string = preg_replace("!\r|\n!m",'',$string);
```